# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1). How do I solve this?

Tags: python, spyder

I have recently started learning how to code and I am using spyder.
I came across this piece of code from a textbook:

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

I understand that this code unpacks argv and assigns it into four different variables. However, when I run this code, I get the following error:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1).

I have tried to look for the solutions online (even came across the same question) but I am unable to solve this code. Can anyone please assist me with this?

Comment: How did you execute the code? What did you expect to be the values of `first`, `second`, and `third`?

Comment: For this code, argv has to have four values (name and three arguments) Normally you check its length to figure out how to handle it, and react accordingly, but this code just assumes you know to type in three arguments. Hopefully that will be more clear if you re-read the text and type in the command line they wanted you to type in.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thank you for your response. How would you write the code? It is still not clear to me how to fix this.

Comment: Make sure to run your script in this sequence `python file_name.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I executed it like shown in the code above but I used the following line of code: script, orange, banana, apple = argv.

Comment: What command did you type to run the code, or where did you click to run the code? What you have shown is the code, but not how you run it.

Comment: @mkrieger I used the run selection or current line option on spyder. I highlighted the code and selected the "Run selection or current line" option. I also used fn + F9

Comment: So how did you expect this to work? Why should there be any arguments in `argv`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I expect it to work the following way:

Comment: The script is called: script
Your first variable is: orange
Your second variable is: banana
Your third variable is: apple

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with your specific GUI but when you run it, there should be either a command line in the project settings, or it should pop up a dialog box asking what arguments to pass. If you don't pass command line arguments, you don't get anything in argv. It's as simple as that. (correction, you get the program name as argv[0] but nothing else)

Comment: @KennyOstrom. Oh right! I think it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should run the code from the terminal something like this

```
python <file name>.py first_arg second_arg third_arg
```